# Python subprocess check_call, native way to print STDERR if it fails?

Tags: python, subprocess

I often wish to perform the action of `subprocess.check_output`, i.e. print STDOUT live, and check the return code is 0 on exit. However  if there is an error, I would like the STDERR to be printed. When looking at log files and just seeing the return code is often not very beneficial.

E.g.:

```py
subprocess.check_call(['ping', '-c', '1', 'github.com2'])
```

Will generate this error:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ping', '-c', '1', 'github.com2']' returned non-zero exit status 2.
```

Here we are left wondering why it failed, on real world examples it becomes critical to be able to see what the actual error is. So I find I always have to wrap such calls in something like this to be able to see STDERR:

```
import subprocess
cmds = ['ping', '-c', '1', 'github.com2']
result = subprocess.run(cmds, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
if result.returncode != 0:
    msg = result.stderr.decode().strip()
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(f"CALLED SUBPROCESS ERROR: Command: {' '.join(cmds)}\nReturn code {result.returncode}\nSTDERR: {msg}\n")
```

With the above one gets to see that STDERR is:

```
ping: github.com2: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I feel there must be a built in way using subprocess, but can't figure it out.

Im guessing it's not possible because CalledSubprocessError does not use STDERR is the string version of the exception:

```
class CalledProcessError(SubprocessError):
    """Raised when run() is called with check=True and the process
    returns a non-zero exit status.

    Attributes:
      cmd, returncode, stdout, stderr, output
    """
    def __init__(self, returncode, cmd, output=None, stderr=None):
        self.returncode = returncode
        self.cmd = cmd
        self.output = output
        self.stderr = stderr

    def __str__(self):
        if self.returncode and self.returncode < 0:
            try:
                return "Command '%s' died with %r." % (
                        self.cmd, signal.Signals(-self.returncode))
            except ValueError:
                return "Command '%s' died with unknown signal %d." % (
                        self.cmd, -self.returncode)
        else:
            return "Command '%s' returned non-zero exit status %d." % (
                    self.cmd, self.returncode)

    @property
    def stdout(self):
        """Alias for output attribute, to match stderr"""
        return self.output

    @stdout.setter
    def stdout(self, value):
        # There's no obvious reason to set this, but allow it anyway so
        # .stdout is a transparent alias for .output
        self.output = value
```

Comment: Have you tried `subprocess.run(..., check=True)`, it raises `subprocess.CalledProcessError` on non zero return and the error has all the info you want, that you can then log with `logging.exception` for example?

Comment: @Tzane, that is perfect! Great idea!! if you make it an answer I can accept it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `subprocess.run(..., check=True)` should provide all the needed info. From the [manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run): "If check is true, and the process exits with a non-zero exit code, a **CalledProcessError** exception will be raised. Attributes of that exception hold **the arguments, the exit code, and stdout and stderr** if they were captured."